# Map instance ID with private IP (VMSS)

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

My hello disapeared, so HELLO

Using the Azure CLI, I need to get the instances-id and private ip of my VMSS instances in one command.

I've already tried :

- `az vmss nic list-vm-nics` : but I only have the private IP
- `az vmss list-instances` : but I only have instance id

Do you know a cli command to get both of them ?

My need is to get instances that are unhealthy in my application gateway (the backend pool is my VMSS) and delete them.

I successfully got the unhealthy ip instances (with the command `az network application-gateway show-backend-health`), but I need to map these IP with an instance ID in order to use this command : `az vmss delete-instances`

And with all az vmss commands, I can't find a way to map a private IP with a instance id...

The goal is to run a job that automatically delete unhealthy instances.

Thanks for your help !
Valentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the virtual machine Id with a known private IP address like this,

```
az vmss nic list -g resourcegroupname --vmss-name vmssname --query "[?ipConfigurations[0].privateIpAddress == '10.0.0.7'].virtualMachine.id" -o tsv
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Thanks Nancy, I found a way before your message by using a query too
But your query is more optimized than mine, so I will use it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I find what I was searching, and I used the query from Nancy, so I put my script here if it can help someone

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -o pipefail

#############
# VARIABLES #
#############

resource_group="your_rg"
appgw_name="your_appgw"
vmss_name="your_vmss"
subscription="your_sub"


##########
# SCRIPT #
##########

az account set --subscription ${subscription}

# Get Actual Backend IPs
backend_ips=$(az network application-gateway show-backend-health --resource-group ${resource_group} --name ${appgw_name} | grep 'address')
backend_ips=$(sed 's/"//g;s/ //g;s/address://g' <<< ${backend_ips})

# Get Backend Health 
backend_health=$(az network application-gateway show-backend-health --resource-group ${resource_group} --name ${appgw_name} | grep 'health\"')
backend_health=$(sed 's/"//g;s/ //g;s/health://g' <<< ${backend_health})

# Get Backend Count
backend_count=$(echo ${backend_ips} | awk -F "," '{print NF-1}')

# Put backend ips and health into tab
IFS=',' read -ra backend_ips <<< "${backend_ips}" 
IFS=',' read -ra backend_health <<< "${backend_health}" 


# SEARCH FOR A UNHEALTHY INSTANCE
for (( i=0; i < ${backend_count}; i++))
do
        echo -e "\n########\n# [IP] ${backend_ips[$i]}"
        echo -e "# [Health] ${backend_health[$i]}\n########\n"

        if [ "${backend_health[$i]}" == "Unhealthy" ]
        then
                echo -e "  -> L'instance ${backend_ips[$i]} est à l'état Unhealthy."
                unhealthy_instance_id=$(az vmss nic list -g ${resource_group} --vmss-name ${vmss_name} --query "[?ipConfigurations[0].privateIpAddress == '${backend_ips[$i]}'].virtualMachine.id" -o tsv | cut -d "/" -f 11)

                echo -e "  -> Suppression de l'instance n°${unhealthy_instance_id}" 
                #az vmss delete-instances -g ${resource_group} -n ${vmss_name} --instance-ids ${unhealthy_instance_id}
        fi
done


exit 0
```